# Seta de voltar para o slide anterior não está funcionando

Tags: javascript

Tudo esta funcionando perfeitamente (tirando o fato da `<img>` piscar antes de passar pra próxima), mas a seta de voltar só repete a mesma `<img>` independente de qual ela seja, a de ir está funcionando normalmente.

```js
$(function(){
    //deslize automático
    var liWidth =$("#slide ul li").outerWidth(),
        speed =5000, /*velocidade do slide*/
        rotate = setInterval(auto,speed);
        
    //mostra os botões
    $("#slide").hover(function(){
        $("#botoes").fadeIn();    
        clearInterval(rotate);
    }, function(){
        $("#botoes").fadeOut();
        rotate = setInterval(auto,speed);
    });  
    
    //próximo
    $(".ir").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        
        $("#slide ul").css({'width':'99999%'}).animate({left:-liWidth}, function(){
            $("#slide ul li").last().after($("#slide ul li").first());
            $(this).css({'left':'0', 'width':'auto'});
        });
    });
    
    //voltar
    $(".voltar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
                
        $("#slide ul li").first().before($("slide ul li").last().css({'margin-left':-liWidth}));
        $("#slide ul").css({'width':'99999%'}).animate({left:liWidth}, function(){
            $("#slide ul li").first().css({'margin-left':'0'});
            $(this).css({'left':'0', 'width':'auto'});
            })
        })
    //deslize automático
    function auto(){
        $(".ir").click();    
    }
});
```

```css
#slide {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
}    
/*botões*/
#slide #botoes {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 5px;
    z-index:500;
}

#slide #botoes a{
    background:#333;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font: bold 23pt Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;/*cor do botão ir voltar*/
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.7;
}
#slide #botoes a:hover { /*fundo do botão ir voltar*/
    background:#555;
}
/*imagens dentra da lista*/
#slide ul {
    list-style:none;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}
#slide ul li {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#slide ul li img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section Id="slide">
        <div id="botoes">
            <a href="#" class="voltar">&lt;</a>
            <a href="#" class="ir">&gt;</a>
        </div>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSBA6VZK0j-lpeTOOG8TKT2poSl9niHAK3NRXuxLlkwyXvkKjZAfA&"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ7Qe6EEF5xKxngWS8FcOxE_y5LQRrGdfUKqEERSZYvXGTMgFu0&"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdHTTJqoCpmSBL2keZFcGwGFkOZKaXlUadgA_p7U1UC374sbJ8&"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlQ6Unn_Tq8EDz21p1gWXcbYd7DE-qijAgwU4OyyM_-OPP-RuA&"></a></li>
     </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Tens como mostrar isso funcionando? Porque não está muito claro

Comment: @Lucas não tenho pq estou desenvolvendo ainda...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não entendi bem.... onde tenho que add a biblioteca JQuery?... Eu tenho ela salva e inclusa no meu projeto... Se tah falando de colocar ela aqui? Como faço isso?

Comment: @luizhenrique o que ele quer é que no minimo você reproduza o problema, veja eu editei o seu código na pergunta e agora ele faz o minimo possivel para os outros entenderem o seu problema, não adiantar colar um monte de coisa e no minimo não conseguir nem reproduzir o problema, assim fica dificil  entender a duvida, mas agora está funcionando :) só falta alguém descobrir o problema do "volar"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento muito obrigado... Agora entendi o que você quis dizer... Ainda estou entendo como devo postar aqui... Muito Obrigado... Abçs

Comment: Achei uma fonte em portugues: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635

Comment: A fácil de entender e usar, na próxima não cometo o mesmo erro...
Vlw ai pela ajuda..

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Na verdade fui eu que alterei o post para usar o StackSnippet, antes ele tinha apenas como o codigo em forma de amostras.

Comment: @TobyMosque entendi, obrigado por relatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro 01 > Faltou identificar o ID do objeto corretamente:

- função "Voltar" : $("slide ul li").last()
- Solução: $("#slide ul li").last()

Erro 02 > Declaração da variavel Global
- Declaração da variavel liWidth dentro de $(function(){})
- Solução: Declarado antes do código como Global

A Função "auto()" coloquei fora de $(function(){}), pois não precisa carregar sendo que já é efetuado a chamada em outras partes do código. Porém não é relativamente um erro.

```js
var liWidth;
$(function(){
 //deslize automático
    var liWidth =$("#slide ul li").outerWidth(),
        speed =5000, /*velocidade do slide*/
        rotate = setInterval(auto,speed);
        
    //mostra os botões
    $("#slide").hover(function(){
        $("#botoes").fadeIn();    
        clearInterval(rotate);
    }, function(){
        $("#botoes").fadeOut();
        rotate = setInterval(auto,speed);
    });  
    
    //próximo
    $(".ir").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $("#slide ul").css({'width':'99999%'}).animate({'left':-liWidth}, function(){
            $("#slide ul li").last().after($("#slide ul li").first());
            $(this).css({'left':'0', 'width':'auto'});
        });
    });
    
    //voltar
    $(".voltar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
  //liWidth = $("#slide ul li").outerWidth();
  
  $("#slide ul li").first().before($("#slide ul li").last().css({'margin-left':-liWidth}));
        $("#slide ul").css({'width':'99999%'}).animate({left:liWidth}, function(){
            $("#slide ul li").first().css({'margin-left':'0'});
            $(this).css({'left':'0', 'width':'auto'});
        })
    });
});
//deslize automático
function auto(){
 $(".ir").click();    
}
```

```css
#slide {
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
   display:block;
   overflow:hidden;
   margin:0;
  }    
  /*botões*/
  #slide #botoes {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   margin: 5px;
   z-index:500;
  }

  #slide #botoes a{
   background:#333;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:50px;
   font: bold 23pt Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   color:#FFF;/*cor do botão ir voltar*/
   text-decoration:none;
   opacity:0.7;
  }
  #slide #botoes a:hover { /*fundo do botão ir voltar*/
   background:#555;
  }
  /*imagens dentra da lista*/
  #slide ul {
   list-style:none;
   display:table;
   position:relative;
  }
  #slide ul li {
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
   display:inline-block;
   position:relative;
  }
  #slide ul li img {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section Id="slide">
        <div id="botoes">
            <a href="#" class="voltar">&lt;</a>
            <a href="#" class="ir">&gt;</a>
        </div>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSBA6VZK0j-lpeTOOG8TKT2poSl9niHAK3NRXuxLlkwyXvkKjZAfA&"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ7Qe6EEF5xKxngWS8FcOxE_y5LQRrGdfUKqEERSZYvXGTMgFu0&"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdHTTJqoCpmSBL2keZFcGwGFkOZKaXlUadgA_p7U1UC374sbJ8&"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlQ6Unn_Tq8EDz21p1gWXcbYd7DE-qijAgwU4OyyM_-OPP-RuA&"></a></li>
   </ul>
 </section>
```